# How to update cell values on a different tab based on criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two tabs, **Sheet 1** and **Sheet 2**, **each with two columns**.

**Sheet 1** is a list of database of barcodes and their status (in the form of dropdown menu).

**Sheet 2** is a list of barcodes scanned and their status (which is not yet entered).

Both sheets have two columns, Column A for "barcode" and Column b for "status".

Every time I scan my products with a barcode scanner, Sheet 2 generates a list of barcodes scanned.

**I want to do the following:**
After creating a barcode list in Sheet 2 and selecting the status of each, I want Sheet 1's status column
to be updated accordingly, reflecting the new status for the corresponding barcode.
And the updated status column in Sheet 1 must remain even after deleting Sheet 2's data.

**For example,**
On Sheet 1's list, there is a database of barcodes from A-1 to A-132, and the status for all are "open".
If I create a list of barcodes on Sheet 2 after scanning from A-1 to A-10 and change the status as "closed", I want Sheet 1 to reflect that change for A-1 and A-10 only.

*(Unfortunately, I cannot have Sheet 1's status column equal Sheet 2's status column because Sheet 2's list has to be deleted on a daily basis.)*
*For example: B1 in Sheet 1 cannot be set as "=Sheet2!B1"*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function updatestatus() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const sh1sr=2;//sheet1 start row
  let vs1=sh1.getRange(sh1sr,1,sh1.getLastRow()-sh1sr+1,2).getValues();
  const sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const sh2sr=2;//sheet2 start row
  const vs2=sh2.getRange(sh2sr,1,sh2.getLastRow()-sh2sr+1,2).getValues();
  const sObj={};//Status object
  vs2.forEach(function(r,i){if(!sObj.hasOwnProperty(r[0])){sObj[r[0]]=r[1];}});
  vs1.forEach(function(r,i){if(sObj.hasOwnProperty(r[0])){r[1]=sObj[r[0]];}});
  sh1.getRange(sh1sr,1,sh1.getLastRow()-sh1sr+1,2).setValues(vs1);//Loads data all at one time
}
```